# Firestore rule to check for field existence results in missing or insufficient permissions error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a read rule on my firestore database as follows:

```
match /messages/{document=**} {
      allow read: if (resource.data.account_id == request.auth.uid 
      && resource.data.keys().hasAll(['is_note']))
      || request.auth.token.role.FirebaseAdminIssuer == true;
    }
```

I believe this should return the user all documents where the account_id field matches their uid and where there the document has a field called is_note.

If I just have the first rule:

```
match /messages/{document=**} {
          allow read: if resource.data.account_id == request.auth.uid 
          || request.auth.token.role.FirebaseAdminIssuer == true;
        }
```

This accurately gives me the documents where the account_id field matches the user uid.

However, when I have manually add a boolean field called is_note to some (not all) documents and set the rule to restrict to documents that also include that, I get `Error: Missing or insufficient permissions.`

Is there something wrong with my rule?

FYI I have used the documentation here to determine rule to use: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/security/#firestore-resource

Comment: I don't understand why I have been given a down-vote. I have given clear description of my problem. I believe I have followed documentation and have looked at other questions to attempt to solve it. Please can the person who down-voted explain their reasoning?

Comment: Are you familiar with the "rules are not filters" concept [described in this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#queries_and_security_rules)?  The wording of your post suggests you expect the rules to filter the results of a query.

Comment: @BobSnyder Thanks for that, I had looked at all the documentation previously but hadn't revisited that with this problem. I'm somewhat confused though as to how the advice given in the doc I was looking at `allow read: if resource.data.keys().hasAll(['name', 'age'])` could ever work given the advice in the other doc that "Cloud Firestore evaluates a query against its potential result set instead of the actual field values"?